# How to debug DCU in Borland Delphi 2006?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2006, dcu

I use Borland Delphi 2006 (folder name: `C:\Program files\borland\BDS\4.0`), and I want to enable `debug DCUs`. Where can I find this option? in tools->options->debugger options it doesn't exist.

Note: I have also Embarcadero developer studio, but I hate it. My project is written under BDS 4.0 too.

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: BDS 4 is borland developer studio 4. The actual Delphi version would be 2006.

Comment: The "debug DCUs" option will have no effect on your package project. Your package requires the rtl and vcl *packages*, and those were not compiled with the debug DCUs. Even if you change the search path to include the units with debug information, the linker is still going to grab the non-debug versions from the configured packages.

Comment: It is not helpful to show us the `Release build (active)` page !

Comment: @moskito-x: Why? The possible option settings are the same...

Comment: @MarjanVenema: That may be. Both settings are the same, only that we can not see

Comment: @moskito-x I checked it before uploading the screenshot. There is no difference between build and debug. By the way, do you know that release can also be compiled with full debug information and not optimizing at all etc.? The only difference between build and debug is which options are checked or not. They are two themes and can theoretically be the same.

Comment: Post your compiler settings page.

Comment: @WarrenP I can't post it because I need 10 reputation to get permitted. But what do you intend? `Pascal Compiler` page? It's an empty page. Only "Please select an option on the left" is written.

Comment: There are a bunch of tabs there under compiler, and NONE of them have Debug DCUs as a visible option?

Comment: So maybe the IDE won't show it to you because your active project is  BPL as said above by Rob. create a new app and see if it shows up.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confused by the fact that *debug .dcu's* is not a debugger option, but a **compiler option**.

Is the compiler the one which generates and includes the symbols required to debug inside the Delphi RTL/VCL.

> The debug DCUILs (.NET) or DCUs (Win32) contain debug information and are built with stack frames. When this option is checked, the compiler prepends the debug DCUIL/DCU path to the unit search path specified in Debug Source Path on the Directories/Conditionals page.

The option is under the compiler options in each project, in:

**Project\Options\Compiler\Debugging\Use debug DCUs**

**Note** I really don't have BDS2006 right now, the closest version I have is BDS2007, but AFAIK the option is named the same.

[image: Use Debug DCUs]

Comment: Sorry. In BDS2006 the menus are displayed in a very different. Under compiler->Debugging option it doesn't exist. (I tried to add a screenshot but stackoverflow doesn't allow for any reason)

Comment: Please, upload your screenshot of the project/options/compiler to a image sharing service and post the link here in a comment.

Comment: @Aharon I found [this screenshot](http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/files/ThemostimportantDelphisetting_9303/DefaultProjectOptions9.png) of the 2006 project options, and it doesn't look too different. Did you uploaded your's?

Comment: It's **very very** different. maybe because I try to compile a package (bpl file). I have some "compiler" options - c++, resources, Pascal - and under Pascal compiler->debugging I have:
`Debug information`
`Local symbol information`
`Symbol reference information`
`Symbol definitions information`
`Enable assertions`.
No more

Comment: @Aharon - We can play the guessing game all day but one single screenshot posted wherever you can would likely solve the confusion.

Comment: @Aharon even Delphi 7 have it there, according to [this screenshot](http://support.smartbear.com/images/support/kb/data/2009/12/1/Delphi_Compiler_TDS.gif). Please, look what is your Delphi Version in Help/About (AFAIK even Delphi 1 have a Help/About) and don't be shy and go publish your screenshot!

Comment: @jachguate I have no account in any sharing pictures site, and have no wish to make one. I can send to your email if you want.

Comment: @Aharon: If you don't have the dialog above, you're not using the version of Delphi you're telling us you are. If you don't/won't post an image to show what your dialog looks like, and can't tell us the proper version, we can't help you here. If you want our help, you must cooperate in giving us the information to use to help you.

Comment: I need 10 reputations to post images. Otherwise stackoverflow doesn't permit

Comment: @Aharon - I've upvoted the question. You now have enough reputation to post an image.

Comment: Does changing the *build configuration* changes anything?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Nothing at all.

Comment: @Aharon, again, look what is your Delphi Version in Help/About and let us know. The non standard dialog may be the work of a IDE expert. What do you have installed there?